# Is this problem of Schinzel and Tijdeman misquoted? It appears easy with Pell equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

In [Diophantine equations over the twentieth century: a (very) brief overview
, p. 5](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/prockyoto.ps)

> **Problem** Let $f(x) \in \mathbf{Z}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree at least 2. Do the Diophantine equation $$f(x)=y^2z^3$$ have only finitely many solutions in non-zero integers $x,y$ and $z$?

The most trivial case is $z=1,f(x)=ax^2+1$ where $a$ is not square.

This leads to the Pell equation $y^2-ax^2=1$, which has infinitely many solutions.

Another approach is let $f(x)=x^2+1$. For fixed $z$, this leads to Pell equation
$x^2-z^3 y^2= -1$. For infinitely many $z$, it has infinitely many solutions $x,y$.

Couldn't find the reference "[13] A. Schinzel and R. Tijdeman, On the equation $y^ m = f(x)$, Acta Arith. 31 (1976),
199-204." online.

> Is the problem misquoted?

Comment: If you google acta arithmetica 1976, guess what you will find.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Many thanks! I already found the same paper, but as far I can tell, the title is different from the cited, which confused me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is indeed misquoted. Here is the correct statement:

> If a polynomial $P(x)$ with rational coefficients has at least three simple zeros then the equation $y^2z^3=P(x)$ has only finitely many solutions in integers $x,y,z$ with $yz\neq 0$.

The paper can be found [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa31/aa3129.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I saw this in another paper. Is it possible this to be another problem? One of the polynomials is over integers, the is over rationals.

Comment: The paper by Schinzel and Tijdeman given as a reference to the problem you ask about only mentions one conjecture, which is this one.

Comment: I edited, adding the paper. Are you quoting the same paper?

Comment: Yes. ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: Is the paper with the same title? (I found another title in the journal). Maybe mistake of the citer.

Comment: Indeed, the title is "On the equation $y^m=P(x)$", by A. Schinzel and R. Tijdeman, from Acta Arithmetica XXXI (1976).

Comment: Why not give link to the paper, it is available online in the same journal.